# can i build a facebook app with an integrated flash player

Tags: facebook

Would it be possible to make a Facebook App for my music blog that showed posts of new songs and had an integrated player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. There are plenty of facebook apps that are just glorified flash games.